# Blackjack help: advice for user about whether to hit or stand

Tags: java, string, blackjack

ok so i am making a blackjack program 
that uses the output box. My problem here is trying to get a sort of help for the user.
i need help finding out what to do at this point:

```
 if (y.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
 {
               if(userHand.getBlackjackValue()+10<21)
               {
                   System.out.println("You should hit.");
               }
               if(userHand.getBlackjackValue()+10>21)
               {

               }
  }
```

The problem is at the second inner if statement. how should it be determined whether or not the player should continue hitting or should stand. I'll include the class as well as other classes in the package pertaining to the program. i am thinking that i might have to add more methods to the project in order to make it work

https://sites.google.com/site/np2701/

if u can please point out some convoluted code that i can fix up, thanks

Comment: I think by "card counting", Patashu meant counting the cards that have already been dealt and calculating the odds of particular cards being drawn next.  What you describe is standard scoring for blackjack.  Do you have a particular algorithm in mind for how to make this decision, or is that your question?  If so, why not just use the same heuristic that Vegas dealers use - hit if 16 or below, stand at 17 or above?

Comment: @StephenCarlson What good is making a hint system that is less intelligent than the player?

Comment: ok i get what he is saying. i am trying to calculate the odds of of particular cards being drawn next that might lead to the score crossing the limit. and based on those odds will it tell the player whether or not to hit. i going to use Stephen Carlson's about the desicion making

Comment: i going to use Stephen Carlson's about the desicion making as a last resort if i cannot find a more accurate approach

Comment: @user2426191 Unless it's for practice reasons, just calculating the odds of busting given you hit next turn isn't enough - you also need to consider, given eahc of the scores you can end up on and how likely, how likely those are to beat the dealer. And also recursively consider that from each of those scores you might hit again, and so on. It's something you'd statically simulate and pre-compute the best possibilities for, rather than try and figure out on the fly.

Comment: @Patashu oh okay; a little clarification; the percentage of how likely i am not going to go over 21 if i hit is what i am trying to get and and beating the dealer. i am not trying to check whether further hits will lead to going over the limit and this all happening in a while loop

Comment: @user2426191 'Will this hit make me bust' is easy, just iterate over every card left in the deck, total up how many make you bust, divide by how many cards total there were, that's the % chance hitting will bust you.

Comment: @Patashu okay this helps me out a lot thanks is there any way i could do this using the methods i the deck class or would i have to make a new method

Comment: @user2426191 I guess write a new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If card counting is out of scope, use a basic strategy table for the rules you are using (number of decks, etc): http://wizardofodds.com/games/blackjack/strategy/calculator/ - you should index into the table based on your hand's point value and the dealer's card, and return the option stored in the table. You might choose to store it in the code as a two dimensional array, or load it from a file. You might store it as characters and interpret what the characters, mean, or as an enum, for example you might call the enum Hints with members Hit, Stand, Split, etc.

A basic strategy table is guaranteed to provide the best odds of success if card counting is ignored, because we take all of the relevant state and chose the statistically best option.

If we wish to account for card counting too, then we must keep track of the True Count (the running high-low count divided by the number of decks left), and for certain states (player hand score vs dealer revealed card) instead of always doing the same action, we do one action if the True Count is above x and another if it is below x. In addition, you should bet next to nothing if the true count is low (below 1) and bet more and more as it increases past 1, but not so much more you run the risk of bankruptcy. Read more here http://wizardofodds.com/games/blackjack/card-counting/high-low/

To represent such an index programatically, I would make an object with three fields: the below-index action, the above-index action and the index value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to suggest the proper play to the user, you need to look up the basic strategy for the game you're simulating. These tables are based on the player's total (and you have to know whether it's soft or hard), and the dealer's upcard.

If all you want to know is "what are my chances of busting on the next hit", that's just (the number of remaining cards that will bust you) / (total remaining cards). This requires not only the player total, but the actual cards. For example, in single deck, if a player has two sevens against a dealer 5, there are 24 bust cards out of the 49 remaining, so you'll bust 24/49 (about 49%) of the time. But if you have a 10 and a 4 (also 14) against a dealer 10, there are only 22 bust cards remaining, for a 45% chance of busting.